# Slideshow: How to jump to different slides with div ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in the middle of building a "product tour". It is being built as a full screen slideshow, I have the `prev` and `next` arrows working for navigation (along with arrow keys). But now that I have a timeline, I can't seem to 'jump to' slides using a `div-id`?

So for example, if I wanted to go from section 1 to section 5, I want to be able to click on my `section 5` button and it jumps to that slide.

[Here is my working example](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3772987986&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=667248&tc_deviceCategory=DESKTOP#). The slider's timeline appears on slide 2+. For the example, I am only working within the `target` sections.

For jQuery, here is all of my code for `binding` and creating the `slider`

```
/* Product Tour */

$(document).ready(function() {
var current = 0;

function previousIndex() {
  var previous = current - 1;
  if(previous == -1) {
      previous = $(".tour-panel").size() -1;
  }
  return previous;
}

function nextIndex() {
  var next = current + 1;
  if(next == $(".tour-panel").size()) {
    next = 0;
  }
  return next;
}

function removeClasses() {
  $(".tour-panel").each(function(index) {
    if(index != current) {
        $(this).removeClass("active-tour");
    }
  })
}

function nextElement() {
  removeClasses();
  $($(".tour-panel")[current]).addClass("fadeOutLeft");
  current = nextIndex();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $($(".tour-panel")[current]).addClass("active-tour fadeInRight");
  }, 50);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $($(".tour-panel")[previousIndex()]).removeClass("active-tour fadeOutLeft");
  }, 750);
}

function previousElement() {
  removeClasses();
  $($(".tour-panel")[current]).addClass("fadeOutRight");
  current = previousIndex();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $($(".tour-panel")[current]).addClass("active-tour fadeInLeft");
  }, 50);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $($(".tour-panel")[nextIndex()]).removeClass("active-tour fadeOutRight");
  }, 750);
}

Mousetrap.bind('left', previousElement);
Mousetrap.bind('right', nextElement);

$(".previous").click(previousElement);
$(".next").click(nextElement);
});
```

I am using an `addClass` and `removeClass` to toggle the active page (or the one you actually see).

Here is the HTML to my timeline as well, you can see that I am just trying to use an `a` tag to swap slides.

```
<ul class="slideshow-timeline">
    <li class="active-target-main"><a href="#target">Target</a>
        <ul class="current-section">
            <li><a href="#target-1">Tracking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-2">Segmentation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-3">Wealth Screening</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-4">Targeting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-5">Cultivation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#connect">Connect</a></li>
    <li><a href="#convert">Convert</a></li>
    <li><a href="#optimize">Optimize</a></li>


</ul>
```

Thanks in advance, I appreciate the help and replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have a fiddle to check this code but I believe the following code should work, at least for those 5 sections.

1. get the `id` of the target which is link's `href` attribute.

   ```
   target_id = $(this).attr('href');
   ```
2. remove the `active-tour` class on current panel

   ```
   removeClasses();
   ```
3. add `active-tour` on current panel(`target_id`) and `fadeInLeft` for animation

   ```
   $(target_id).addClass("active-tour fadeInLeft");
   ```
4. remove the exit animation class(`fadeOutRight`) on the "previous" panel

   ```
   $($(".tour-panel")[current]).removeClass("fadeOutRight");
   ```
5. finally, set the `current` panel index

   ```
   current = target_id.split('-')[1] || 0;
   ```

so,

```
$('.current-section li a').click(function() {
    var target_id = $(this).attr('href');
    removeClasses();
    $($(".tour-panel")[current]).addClass("fadeOutRight");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(target_id).addClass("active-tour fadeInLeft");
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $($(".tour-panel")[current]).removeClass("fadeOutRight");
    }, 750);
    current = target_id.split('-')[1] || 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Venugopal! I have it set up on the **[preview](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3772987986&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=667248&tc_deviceCategory=DESKTOP)** now, but I think the `setTimeout` functions are restricting it's functions. For example, after clicking to jump to a page, clicking to another page will drop the `active-tour` class, but will not add it to another. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I found that it would let me go to a link, then if I tried to do it again it wouldn't append a "active-tour" class to the next element (showing a blank page). After removing the `current = target_id.split('-')[1] || 0;` it now lets me go between multiple pages, but after the first successful page jump, it will always show the intro slide, or `#target`.

Comment: in the preview, only first panel got links in the format `<a href="#target-1">Tracking</a>`. in the remaining panels links are in `<a href="#">Tracking</a>`. so the `target_id` is coming as `#` instead of `#target-X`. please check that

Comment: Oh my god, this just hit me like a brick. Sorry about all the questions. I only updated the first version of the nav! I really appreciate all the help. This works, but you don't need to set the current panel index at the end. 

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: i think setting current panel index is needed for `prev` and `next` arrows to work.

Comment: the preview has it removed and everything seems to work.

When it was set, the arrow buttons and keys would not work. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by refactoring you JS. We'll add a function that could also be used for the arrow navigation. It might look something like this:

First we will create some variables (because storing is usually faster than creating jQuery-objects):

```
var current = 0,
    $panels = $('.tour-panel'),
    noOfPanels = $panels.size() - 1,
    $currentElement = $panels.eq(current),
    $nextElement = $currentElement,
    $links = $('.slideshow-timeline a');
```

In this example it is important that `$links` and `$panels` contain the same number of elements. Now we can write our function that changes our `$panels`:

```
function anyElement( slidePosition ) {
    $nextElement = $panels.eq(next);
    if (slidePosition > current) {
        $currentElement.removeClass('active-tour');
        $currentElement.addClass('fadeOutLeft');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $nextElement.addClass('active-tour fadeInRight');
        }, 50);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $currentElement.removeClass('fadeOutLeft');
        }, 750);
    } else if (slidePosition < current) {
        $currentElement.removeClass('active-tour');
        $currentElement.addClass('fadeOutRight');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $nextElement.addClass('active-tour fadeInLeft');
        }, 50);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $currentElement.removeClass('fadeOutRight');
        }, 750);
    } else {
        // in this case the element selected and the one showing are the same
        // there are no class changes to be applied
    }
    current = slidePosition;
    $currentElement = $nextElement;
}
```

The function takes the Argument `slidePosition` (a number representing the `index` of the new `panel`) and changes the appropiate classes.

Now all left to do is binding the function to user interactions.

If one of our matched `$links` is `clicked` we check it's `index` and use it as the argument for our new function.

```
$links.on('click', function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    var next = $links.index(this);
    anyElement( next );
});
```

We handle the arrows and `Mousetrap` in a similar manner. Knowing the `current` position we calculate the desired one (taking into consideration the maximum number of `panels`).

```
$('.previous').click(function () {
    var previous;
    if (current === 0) {
        previous = noOfPanels;
    } else {
        previous = current - 1;
    }
    anyElement( previous );
});
Mousetrap.bind('left', function () {
    var previous;
    if (current === 0) {
        previous = noOfPanels;
    } else {
        previous = current - 1;
    }
    anyElement( previous );
});

$('.next').click(function () {
    var next;
    if (current === noOfPanels) {
        next = 0;
    } else {
        next = current + 1;
    }
    anyElement( next );
});
Mousetrap.bind('right', function () {
    var next;
    if (current === noOfPanels) {
        next = 0;
    } else {
        next = current + 1;
    }
    anyElement( next );
});
```

I didn't have time to test this but believe it should work. As mentioned above it is important that `$links` and `$panels` have the same number of elements and are in the same order.

(There is some overhead. You might want to remove some of the global variables and instead use arguments.)

On a side node:

```
$('.myClass').eq(5)
```

returns a jQuery object and is (from what I am told) significantly faster than

```
$($('.myClass')[5])
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this replaces all my JS and I need to add the `.js-goto-panel` to each slide?

Comment: Yes it replaces most of your JS. I didn't add the Mousetrap binding but it should be identical to the arrow bindings. The .js-goto-panel should be added to the <a>-tags. I added them for simplicity - it's just important that "$links" only contains the relevant <a>-tags (meaning you could also use another css-style selector in the JS. I'm on the move right now and can't do proper code styling but will edit my answer accordingly when I get to a machine.